# How would i continue with my small casino game?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and have made a casino game. To bet in this game you write "bet100". You write bet + how much money you want to bet. How would I make so that the winnings become bigger/smaller depending on how much you decide to bet? How would I code this?

```
import random
print("CasinoGame") #Miriam
money = 1000
gameActive = True
while gameActive:
    bet = input("""Write "bet" to bet 100$""")
    bet_len = len(bet)
    if bet_len == 0:
        print("bet is empty")
    bet_type = bet[:3]
    print(bet_type)
    amount = 0
    if bet_len > 3:
        num_string = bet[3:]
        amount = int(num_string)
    print(bet, bet_type, amount)
```

Comment: If you - for example - give the user the chance to double up, winnings would be lower/bigger depending how much you choose to bet. Is that your question?

Comment: You should add user input to allow the change of the sum, the user want's to bet first.

Comment: Im sorry for my English, i know how i could implement so that you can win/loose but how would i do it so that if your bet is like 150 the winnings can be more than they are when the bet is 100?

Comment: What do you mean Dschoni, what is Before the user bets that should be after?

Comment: If you just multiply the the bet with 2, the player will win 150$ with a 150$ bet and 100$ with a 100$ bet. Or do you want to implement something like a function so the win ratio increases with the size of the bet?

Comment: Im thinking about something like the ratio idea, ime new to programming thats probraly too hard for me tho.

Comment: lets say when user wins they get double the money. If you put user bet in a variable then have something like `winnings = user_bet * 2` then it will automatically give the right value. user bet of 100 will give winnings a value of 200 user bet of 150 will give winnings a value of 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your casino game (the real game here is a coinflip, but you could use whatever you want to implement) could look like this:

```
import random

print("CasinoGame") 
money = 1000

while True:
    # 1) ask if player wants to continue to play
    continue_play = input('Write "bet" if you want to continue to play or "quit" if you want to leave the casino.\n')
    # if not: break the loop
    if continue_play == 'quit': break
    # if typo or something: ask again (next iteration)
    if continue_play != 'bet': continue
    # ask for bet size (has to be integer)
    bet = int(input(f'Enter the amount you want to bet (in numbers).\nYour money: {money}\n'))
    # check if user is able to make the bet, if not: tell how much money is left and start again (next iteration)
    if bet > money: 
        print(f'Sorry, but you cannot bet more money than you have. Your money: {money}.\n')
        continue
    # calculate possible winnings (bigger if the bet is bigger)
    # you could also do something like a exponential function
    poss_win = bet*3
    # flip a coin
    coin = random.randint(0,1)
    # see if the user won 
    if coin == 1: 
        win = True
    else:
        win = False
    # evaluate: give money if win, take if loose
    if win:
        print(f'Congratulations, you won {poss_win}.')
        money = money - bet + poss_win
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, but you lost {bet}.')
        money = money - bet
    # if the user is broke: throw him out of the casino 
    if money == 0:
        print('Sorry, you are broke. Thank you, come again.')
        break

# see & tell if user made or lost money (or is even)
if money < 1000:
    losses = 1000 - money
    print(f'You lost {losses} and have now {money}.')
elif money == 1000:
    print('You have neither lost nor won something.')
else:
    winnings = money - 1000
    print(f'Congratulations, you have won {winnings} and have now {money}.')
```

Note that f-string only work in python versions >3.6. Also, if the user inputs something else than an integer as a bet, the script will break. You could implement a `try` and `except` statement to avoid that.